# RadioGroup extending RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to make a grid of radio buttons for my app, what I have learned is that this isn't possible using regular `RadioGroup` because it extends LinearLayout and if you try to arrange the `RadioButtons` using RelativeLayout INSIDE the `RadioGroup` the `RadioGroup` doesn't see the `Buttons` inside the `RelativeLayout`.

So in order to fix this I want to make a custom RadioGroup that extends RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

How do I do this?

UPDATE: I did what you said but I have these errors I don't know how to fix in the class file:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
RadioGroup_checkedButton cannot be resolved or is not a field   RadioGroupRelative.java /BlockBall/src/com/stickfigs/blockball  line 81 Java Problem
The constructor RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(int, int, float) is undefined   RadioGroupRelative.java /BlockBall/src/com/stickfigs/blockball  line 265    Java Problem
The method setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) is undefined for the type RadioButton   RadioGroupRelative.java /BlockBall/src/com/stickfigs/blockball  line 363    Java Problem
The method setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener(null) is undefined for the type RadioButton RadioGroupRelative.java /BlockBall/src/com/stickfigs/blockball  line 377    Java Problem
VERTICAL cannot be resolved to a variable   RadioGroupRelative.java /BlockBall/src/com/stickfigs/blockball  line 68 Java Problem
Widget_CompountButton_RadioButton cannot be resolved or is not a field  RadioGroupRelative.java /BlockBall/src/com/stickfigs/blockball  line 79 Java Problem
```

Comment: [Try processing the RadioButtons without the use of RadioGroup.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332042/setting-up-a-radiogroup-programmatically/7019673#7019673

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get the `RadioGroup`'s source code from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/RadioGroup.java;h=393346a314f7b1ad20c617c494904f599391c081;hb=HEAD), replace all entries of `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout`.

Add this code to some xml file in your project (usually its name is attrs.xml):

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RadioGroup">
        <attr name="android:checkedButton" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Replace `RadioGroup`'s constructors with these:

```
public RadioGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        init();
    }
}

public RadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.RadioGroup, 0,
                android.R.style.Widget_CompoundButton_RadioButton);

        int value = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.RadioGroup_checkedButton,
            View.NO_ID);
        if (value != View.NO_ID) {
            mCheckedId = value;
        }

        attributes.recycle();
        init();
    }
}
```

Remove the following constructor from the `LayoutParams` inner class:

```
public LayoutParams(int w, int h, float initWeight) {
    super(w, h, initWeight);
}
```

Replace all occurrences of `setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener()` method calls with the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method. **IMPORTANT**: In this case it won't be possible to use this method from a code that uses this widget.

Haven't tried this but hope this will work.

Comment: This sounds good, but what is the XML and the changes to the constructor for? I was thinking just repalce LinearLayout with RelativeLayout and that would be enough, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. It won't just compile, because some internal fields are used in `RadioGroup'`s constructor. That's why you need this xml. It allows you to redefine `android:checkedButton` attribute for the `RadioGroup` widget. And changes to the constructor are necessary because you need to use values from the xml.

Comment: Ok I did what you said, I have some errors in the new class file though, added them to the question above...

Comment: 1) Attrs.xml file must have resources as the root tag. Added it to the answer. 2) Just remove this constructor. 3,4) That's a problem. This method is package-private, so it's not available from your code. You can use 'setOnCheckedChangeListener', but you won't be able to use it in other parts of code in this case. 5) Remove line `setOrientation(VERTICAL)` from the constructor. 6) That was just a type in the word Compound. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: I added all these fixes to the answer.

Comment: Hi @Michael, I'm trying to implement this but I get the following error: `Style with id 0x103001a (resolved to 'Widget_CompoundButton_RadioButton') does not exist.` At xml Graphical Layout view. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I have missed that at `RadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`.

Comment: I have to say thanks! I was able to get this working for me! Had an issue with R.styleable not finding the RadioGroup checkedButton in my attrs.xml but I just renamed it and it found it fine then.

Comment: Note: After getting this working, I added a project with the changes to github: https://github.com/valheru7/RelativeRadioGroup

Answer (score 2):

Copy the source for RadioGroup from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/RadioGroup.java;h=393346a314f7b1ad20c617c494904f599391c081;hb=HEAD) and edit it to change it to extend RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

This is out of topic, but in case if you wanna do the same thing with `ConstraintLayout` then the code is [available at Github](https://github.com/DaemonDhruv/ConstraintRadioGroup)

You can import the library and use the widget `ConstraintRadioGroup`