# Custom RelativeLayout children ignoring all positioning "android:layout_" attributes

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm going completely mad.

I'm attempting to create a RadioGroup that extends RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. Seems easy enough. I'm following [this] exactly. Everything's double and triple checked. This seems to have worked for a bunch of other people just fine.

Upon actually using it, the RelativeLayout attributes specified by the children are completely ignored. Everything piles up in the top left and nothing I can do will move them.

If I change the view from RadioGroupRelative to a regular RelativeLayout, everything is suddenly following the 'android:layout_' attributes perfectly. Looks exactly the way I want it to look.

So. Somewhere along the lines, and I've redone this like 5 times now, I'm losing those xml attributes. I don't understand *how* though. RadioGroup doesn't do anything to it's children's layout parameters from what I can tell. Why aren't they getting applied when android inflates the layout?

Comment: It seems you missed to post the link you are referring for coding.

Comment: Gah, sorry, messed up the formating or something. [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320125/radiogroup-extending-relativelayout). I'll add code in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no link for [this] - could you add it? Also, mind posting your source code for your custom RadioGroup that inherits from RelativeLayout. From what i can tell, RadioGroup is-a LinearLayout so I'm assuming you've copied and customized the Android source code to do this...

EDIT: as a test, what does the following code do in your environment?

```
YourCustomRadioGroup radioGroup = new YourCustomRadioGroup(this);
if (radioGroup instanceof RelativeLayout){
   //do you end up in here?
   Log.d("yourapp","I'm a RelativeLayout!!");
}else{
   Log.d("yourapp","I'm NOT a RelativeLayout! :( ");
}
```